# Is there a tighter approximation for the least prime gap of a given length?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

This link

https://primes.utm.edu/notes/gaps.html

gives a definition of the maximal gaps. For a number $g$ , $p(g)$ is the
smallest prime $p$ followed by at least $g$ composites. The estimate is 
$\ln{p(g)}\approx \sqrt{g}$ and it is refined in the link.

But the approximation is far from tight comparing it with the values of the
table.

- Is a better approximation known for $p(g)$ ?
- What are the tightest lower and upper bounds known for $p(g)$ ?

Comment: Have a look at the Related questions listed on this page, maybe you'll find your question was asked previously and someone has already answered it.

Comment: I found a formula for the reverse : $$N\ge 7\ \ \ max_{p_{n+1}\le N} \ \ p_{n+1}-p_n\approx log(N)(log(N)-2log(log(N)))+2$$. This fits very well with the calculated values.